# Hwo to find sublist of increasing length in python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Suppose,
n = 6 (length of list)
lis = [3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1] (my list)

I need list of sublists with maximum increasing length before last element.
which is:
[[3], [2, 3], [4, 3, 1]] (first element with length 1, second with length 2 and so on)

if the lis was of 5 elements: lis = [3, 2, 3, 4, 3]
the result should be
[[3], [2, 3]] because there aren't three elements ahead

Comment: Can you please share what did you try so far

Comment: do the values need to be increasing as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
def cut(l):
    i = 1
    pos = 0
    out = []
    while pos<len(l)-i+1:
        out.append(l[pos:pos+i])
        pos += i
        i += 1
    return out

cut([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
```

output:

```
[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

##### variant

Other approach for fun if we do not want to test position relative to the end at each step.

The sum of the first n integers is `x = n*(n+1)/2`, we can calculate that, given `x`, `n = int((math.sqrt(1+8*x)-1)/2)`. This enables us to directly know how many steps there are:

```
# function to calculate the number of steps from the list length
def nb(x):
    import math
    return int((math.sqrt(1+8*x)-1)/2)
# nb(11) -> 4

def cut(l):
    pos = 0
    out = []
    for i in range(1, nb(len(l))+1):
        out.append(l[pos:pos+i])
        pos += i
    return out

cut([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
```

Answer (score 1):

The most comfortable solution:

```
np.split(lis, np.cumsum(range(len(lis))))
```

or, using a bit math here:

```
np.split(lis, np.cumsum(range(int(np.ceil(np.sqrt(9/4 + 2*len(lst)) - 3/2)))))
```

Solutions without numpy:

```
[lst[sum(range(i+1)):sum(range(i+1)) + i + 1] for i in range(len(lst)) if len(lst[sum(range(i+1)):])>=i]
```

output:
`[[3], [2, 3], [4, 3, 1]]`

a little shorter

```
[lst[l:l + i + 1] for i in range(len(lst)) if len(lst[(l := sum(range(i+1))):])>=i]
```

As @mozway mentioned, this approach is slower, due to the repeated evaluation of the cumulative sum.
One could alter this approach:

```
l = 0
[lst[l:(l := l + i + 1)] for i in range(len(lst)) if len(lst[l:])>=i]
```

This is a bit hacky, but great fun, nevertheless.

Now, to make use of some basic math here, one can get reasonably fast

```
[lst[i*(i+1)//2 : (i+1)*(i+2)//2] for i in range(int(np.ceil(np.sqrt(9/4 + 2*len(lst)) - 3/2)))]
```

At first this was my answer:

```
[lst[i:2*i + 1] for i in range(len(lst)) if len(lst[i:])>=i]
```

but this starts at previously used items

output:
`[[3], [2, 3], [3, 4, 3], [4, 3, 1]]`

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: nevermind... I misread the instructions

Comment: Na, I think you were right. My first answer was not what OP asked for. I corrected my answer now. Thanks.

Comment: I think the solution is inefficient. looks like a quadratic complexity to me

Comment: Indeed, quick test on 20k items, `153 µs ± 10.7 µs` for [my linear approach](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72752534/edit), `3.48 s ± 389 ms` for this one. It doesn't even run for higher lengths. Using list comprehensions is nice but it should neither affect explicitness, nor efficiency ;)

Comment: this might well be, indeed

Comment: however, one could use a little hack, just for the fun; let me try something

Comment: Better, but still a ~100x difference in timing: `11.2 ms ± 673 µs` vs `85.4 µs ± 1.4 µs` (20k)

Comment: Yeah, now I think it is due to the iteration not being stopped...back to the blackboard ;-)

Comment: that should be very fast now

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing an another option out there using some `itertools`... so it'll work on anything that can be iterated over and not just objects that support slicing.

```
from itertools import count, islice

# Make a generator so take the first N elements of what's remaining each time until we get an empty list...
chunk_iter = iter(lambda it=iter(lis), size=count(1): list(islice(it, next(size))), [])
# Filter out those to drop entries not matching the expected length (eg: drop last element if needed)
valid_chunks = (el for n, el in enumerate(chunk_iter, 1) if len(el) == n)

# Iterate over the above or optionally materialise into a list of lists...
# (and ignoring the very last entry if it's not the length of the number we're expecting)
res = list(valid_chunks)
```

Probably much nicer to wrap it into a more readable generator function though, eg:

```
def f(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    for size in count(1):
        val = list(islice(it, size))
        if len(val) != size:
            break
        yield val
```